# Error when using client code with Expresso

Tags: java, xml, http, xml-parsing

I started using expresso paser (www.sxml.com.au) last week after seeing it mentioned as a solution on this website. I created a free account, logged in, uploaded an XML file and parsed  the file. I could see the results fine on the screen. I then generated client code in java and I ran it.

I was running the non-SSL version using HTTP and I got this error back from the SXML server.

Has anybody else experience with this?

Please help as I need to integrate this into a project as soon as possible!!

Here the part of my client code which connects to the SXML server and makes the request.

```
String username = "adamCoyle";
String password = ""; //ADD PASSWORD HERE
String connectionName = "test1";
String company = "student";
String remoteSXMLURL="http://sxml.com.au:8080/Expresso/RemoteSXML";
/*
 * Non- SSL mode
 */
/*
* For SSL mode, uncomment the following code and follow certificate installation     instructions in help section
* of website to install the SSL cert into the CA keystore
*/
//String remoteSXMLURL="https://sxml.com.au:8444/Expresso/RemoteSXML";

String urlParams ="";

String fileLocation = "server";

String fileForXMLUpload = "";

if(fileForXMLUpload!="")

{

File xmlFileToBeUploadedFile = new File (fileForXMLUpload);

fileForXMLUpload="";

if(xmlFileToBeUploadedFile.exists())

{

BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (xmlFileToBeUploadedFile));

while(bfr.ready())

{

fileForXMLUpload+=bfr.readLine();

}

}

}

String mode= "all";

String isCached = "false";

String areRulesSimple ="false";

String dynamicParamaters ="";

String sortBy ="";

/* step 2 - make a https connection */

URL sxml = new URL(remoteSXMLURL);

HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) sxml.openConnection();

/* step 3- add the paramaters to the HTTPS connection */

String urlParameters = "username="

+ URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&password="

+ URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&connectionName="

+ URLEncoder.encode(connectionName, "UTF-8") + "&company="

+ URLEncoder.encode(company, "UTF-8") + "&fileLocation="

+ URLEncoder.encode(fileLocation, "UTF-8") + "&fileForXMLUpload="

+ URLEncoder.encode(fileForXMLUpload, "UTF-8") + "&mode="

+ URLEncoder.encode(mode, "UTF-8") + "&isCached="

+ URLEncoder.encode(isCached, "UTF-8") + "&areRulesSimple="

+ URLEncoder.encode(areRulesSimple, "UTF-8") + "&dynamicParamaters="

+ URLEncoder.encode(dynamicParamaters, "UTF-8") + "& urlParams ="

+ URLEncoder.encode(urlParams, "UTF-8") + "&sortBy="

+ URLEncoder.encode(sortBy, "UTF-8");

/* step 4- set the properties for the HTTPS connection */

/*

* properties

* requestMethod - The HTTPS request will always be a POST request

* Content-Type - The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* content-Length - This is the length of the paramaters

*

*/

yc.setRequestMethod("POST");

yc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

yc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

yc.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

yc.setDoOutput(true);

/* step 5 - push out request to HTTPS server */

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(yc.getOutputStream());

wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);

wr.flush();

wr.close();
```

Comment: Definitely they will reuse the name of frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, thanks for using SXML. We are really pushing to get as many devs using it as possible.

I looked through your client code and there is a missing field. For using Expresso XML parser you need to supply a password. this is the same password you would have used to login to your GUI account. your password is not automatically added to the client code for security reasons but you need it to connect.

Find the part of the code which says

String password = ""; //ADD PASSWORD HERE

Add your password in place of the blank string and try to connect again. You should be able to connect.

Please let me know whether you have any other further problems.

Laura Cavanagh
www.sxml.com.au